# I can't login for administrator access

Tags: 20.04, login, sudo, laptop, administrator

So whenever I try to use sudo commands on my Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop(I have a partition for Ubuntu) and I am asked to type password ,even though I type in correct password I get a notification saying "sorry that didn't work,please try again"

Comment: This means that you type a wrong password.

Comment: Is there anyway to change it?

Comment: tried it didn't work.

Comment: initially I couldn't even login to my account but now I can but can't use sudo commands

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have the wrong password. Assuming your installation is quite fresh, and you haven't modified it a lot, I would recommend wiping the partition and re-installing it. Alternativly, if you do not want to do that you can look at this answer: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: This answer is basically a duplicate of [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452201/i-cant-login-for-administrator-access#comment2536342_1452201) to the main question which was posted before you posted this answer.